# MySQL Query taking a long time to display

Tags: php, mysql

The following code works but it takes minutes for the page to load. Basically, I am querying the database for any upcoming events and totaling the quantity column for each event. There are less than 30 active events and an average of 30 tickets per event.

Thanks.

```
<?php

$rowsquery="SELECT *
FROM listings
WHERE show_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
ORDER BY show_date";
$result=mysql_query($rowsquery);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

?>


<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$item_number=mysql_result($result,$i,"item_number");
$show_date=mysql_result($result,$i,"show_date");
$show_time=mysql_result($result,$i,"show_time");
$headline=mysql_result($result,$i,"headline");
$double_head=mysql_result($result,$i,"double_head");
$price=mysql_result($result,$i,"price");
$opening_stock=mysql_result($result,$i,"opening_stock");
$available_online=mysql_result($result,$i,"available_online");
$booking_fee=mysql_result($result,$i,"booking_fee");
$total_price=$price+$booking_fee;

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$total = "SELECT SUM(i.quantity) as total_tickets 
FROM paypal_ipn_orders o, paypal_ipn_order_items i
WHERE i.item_number = '$item_number'
AND i.raw_log_id = o.raw_log_id
AND o.payment_status != 'Refunded'
ORDER BY UPPER(o.last_name)";
$sRow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($total));
$totaltkts = $sRow['total_tickets'];

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: so what's your question? also you should show your database schema

Comment: remove `UPPER`..  so `ORDER BY (o.last_name)"; ` where does your while end?

Comment: Any specific reason why your `mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);` is below your previous query? Connect first, then query.

Comment: you're doing a connection on EVERY iteration of your loop? That is LUDICROUSLY inefficient, plus pulling out values with `mysql_result` is similarly bad.

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to teach myself as I go and I changed the code above recently as it was not taking into account that 'Refunded' tickets were not to be included in the total. That's when I added the second SELECT statement and I guessed it was inefficient due to the time it takes to display the results.

The code I was using previously without issue was...

$total = "SELECT SUM(quantity) as total_tickets FROM paypal_ipn_order_items WHERE item_number='$item_number'";
$sRow = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($total));
$totaltkts = $sRow['total_tickets'];

Comment: Should I leave the connection open after my initial query and then not include the DB connection in the loop?

Comment: I figured out what the main part of my problem was... I had copied the select statement from another area in my code and then edited it as needed. However I didn't remove the Order by 'last name' which I had not included in this instance.

Thanks for your input... I will try to clean up the rest of my code too.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have index in database on all fields in where clause - item_number, raw_log_id, payment_status